# Navigattion to other web pages from index page in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

i am newbie in codeigniter,I am facing a problem while i am trying to navigate my other pages from my index pages...i have make anchor link properly to navigate the page i am wanting..as a exaple..

i want to navigate my `reservation` page...then in my index page this link is given like this..

```
<a href ="book_table.php">Reservation</a>
```

My `book_table` resides in the `view` folder of the codeigniter framework and `index.php` obviously resides in `view` folder too, my controller is just like that..

```
 <?php


class Saffron extends CI_Controller

 {

   function index()
      {

           $this->load->view('index');

      } 


}
```

Now the problem is that while i am trying to naviagate my `reservation` page from the `index.php` page its showing 'No page found' that is its not finding the  `book_table` page.Why its happening?? may b i m missing something here,u r the expert please help me..advance thanks.

Comment: I guess you need to start reading some basic controller FAQ's. Nettuts instruction videos might be a place to start... ( you dont link to a view, but to a controller method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codeigniter is based on MVC. and your href is just a php file. In MVC it should be some controller and an action of that controller.

Read it here. http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html

Answer (score 1):

You have to create function in controller say "**reservation**"

```
function reservation()
{    
  $this->load->view('book_table');    
}
```

and on index page write like this :-

```
<a href ="<?php echo base_url();?>saffron/reservation">Reservation</a>
```

**NOTE :-**

base_url() - you have to define your site url in application->config->config.php file

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.example.com/';
```

Answer (score 0):

first set your base_url()
and then when redirecting
do something like this:

```
<a href='<?=base_url()?>home/funct_name' >Navigation</a>
```

home is the name of your controller